# MissingMethodException Flurry WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7, flurry

Some devices/users send error reports like this:

```
System.MissingMethodException: MissingMethodException
   at FlurryWP7SDK.Api.LogEvent(String eventName)
   at ViewModel.MainViewModel.OnCallCommandExecuted()
```

Reinstalling doesn't help

Comment: In your project, click the reference to the FlurryWP7SDK and in the properties window flip **Specific Version** to *true*.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/sbJ0D.png  See if that gives you a better error message.  Probably two different versions of that dll installed on the phone; not familiar with how WP7 phones handle assembly loading, so no answer.

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem I'm having similar issues

Comment: @JamesMundy not sure if it's fixed. Seems that kind of issues is submitted by developers (if you have a team) and when all they have different SDK referenced. I noticed VS2010 sometimes takes DLL from /bin/Debug instead of /External Binaries one referenced in .csproj

Comment: yea just worked it out myself you have to ensure that there are no other versions lying around. Solved by deleting all built items and rebuilding